# Search and find a DIV's content by classname

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `div` element that contains other `div` elements which have class names created dynamically.
I need to search the container `div` elements' content and find the `div` elements by the first 3 letters of their class name.

Example:

```
<div>
  <div class="CTR-???????">
  </div>
  <div class="CTR-???????">
  </div>
  <div class="CTR-???????">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm sure there is a way to do this with Javascript but I couldn't find that way.

Can anyone help?

Comment: jQuery is ideal for performing this sort of task. Is there any reason you need to do it in plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Native JavaScript Solution

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) combined with the [`^=` substring-matching attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings):

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="CTR"]');
```

This will return a NodeList containing the matched elements, which looks like an array:

```
> [<div class="CTR-???????"></div>,
   <div class="CTR-???????"></div>,
   <div class="CTR-???????"></div>]
```

You can then access the individual selected elements by their index:

```
elems[0];
> <div class="CTR-???????"></div>
```

#### Working Demo

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="CTR"]');

elems[0].style.color = '#f00';
elems[1].style.color = '#0f0';
elems[2].style.color = '#00f';
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="CTR-???????">1</div>
  <div class="CTR-???????">2</div>
  <div class="CTR-???????">3</div>
</div>
```

### jQuery Solution

If you're using jQuery, you can simply pass the same string I used in the above `querySelectorAll` example into a jQuery selector:

```
$('div[class^="CTA"]')
```

#### Working Demo

```js
var elems = $('div[class^="CTR"]');

$(elems[0]).css('color', '#f00');
$(elems[1]).css('color', '#0f0');
$(elems[2]).css('color', '#00f');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="CTR-???????">1</div>
  <div class="CTR-???????">2</div>
  <div class="CTR-???????">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign some more classes:

```
<div>
  <div class="CTR CTR-???????">
  </div>
  <div class="CTR CTR-???????">
  </div>
  <div class="CTR CTR-???????">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can find these by looking for `.CTR`. In jQuery this would be `$('.CTR')` or in plain JS `document.getElementsByClassName('CTR')`

Comment: You really don't need to do this. You can select a class which starts with CTR, so adding new classes is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @fboes that's all well and good, but you're firstly ignoring the fact that with your solution you have to add the new class name (which isn't present in your JSPerf test), and secondly unless OP is running a game at 60fps the difference here is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class^="CTR-"], [class*=" CTR-"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery you can easily do this by selecting the `div`'s with a class starting with `CTR` and also check if they contain the search term like this:

```
$('div[class^="CTR"]:contains("Term that content has to require")').each(function() {
// do something
});
```